# Ruby, Rails - how to check if a var is an Email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, email-validation

Does Rails 3 or Ruby have a built in way to return true or false on if a var is an EMAIL ADDRESS?

example

```
1 returns false
dadadad@asdasd.net returns true
blah+asdasds@asdasd.net returns true
asdasdasdads returns false
```

Maybe something like, if 1.is_a? Email end

thanks

Comment: The problem with trying to validate an email address is that the allowed address formats are too varied to handle with a simple regex. Even a complex regex can't catch all the corner cases, but, even if one could determine if the address format was correct, it still wouldn't be able to tell if it was a real address. Because of the complexity of the problem there are two solutions: send an email to the address and see if the receiver responds, or do a simplistic check for user id, an '@' and a domain, and call it good enough. The second is trivially easy to spoof.

Comment: For an in-depth discussion of this topic, see [How to use a regular expression to validate an email addresses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-use-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-addresses)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up using the Rails gem, [EmailVeracity](https://github.com/heycarsten/email-veracity) which worked great

Comment: the library is deprecated and the last commit was 6 years ago.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this should work:

```
def isEmail(str)
  return str.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9._%]@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]\.)[a-zA-Z]{2,4}/)
end
```

Comment: You can't validate email addresses using a regular expression. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses/201378#201378

Comment: @Andrew then what should I use if I can use a regex?

Comment: This wouldn't work for most domains, because you allow domain name to be just single letter, like foo@a.com. Probably you wanted to write this one: `/[a-zA-Z0-9._%]@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)[a-zA-Z]{2,4}/`

Answer (score 1):

In a model you can use validators (in ActiveModel) along with a

something like this:

```
class User
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  validates :email, :presence => true,
                    :format => {:with => /^[^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9A-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})$/}

end
```

see http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/
for more on ActiveModel

Comment: You can't validate email addresses using a regular expression. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses/201378#201378

Comment: He only asked for a subset of email addresses, not the whole RFC.

Comment: By that logic, `def is_email(str) str =~ /asd/ end` would do what he literally asked for?

Comment: There's a syntax error in that regular expression `^([^@\s]+)@([-a-z0-9A-Z]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,})$` would match at least some email address.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/OpenGems/rails_email_checker

ActiveModel email validation. Checks MX records, sub address, regex, whitelisted and blacklisted check